# Selecting rows in pandas based on threshold date per id

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I want to select rows from my pandas DataFrame where records are before a certain date for each id.

I have some threshold dates for each id:

```
thresholds = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1, 2, 3], 'threshold_date':pd.date_range('2019-01-01', periods = 3)})
thresholds
    id  threshold_date
0   1   2019-01-01
1   2   2019-01-02
2   3   2019-01-03
```

I have a DataFrame with dates after the threshold date for each id:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], 'threshold_date':pd.date_range('2018-12-30', periods = 6), 'value': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3]})
df
    id  threshold_date  value
0   1   2018-12-30      0.1
1   1   2018-12-31      0.2
2   2   2019-01-01      0.3
3   2   2019-01-02      0.1
4   3   2019-01-03      0.2
5   3   2019-01-04      0.3

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1, 1, 2], 'threshold_date':pd.date_range('2018-12-30', periods = 3), 'value': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]})
```

I would like to filter my DataFrame so that I only have rows before the threshold date for each id:

```
df_filt = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1, 1, 2], 'threshold_date':pd.date_range('2018-12-30', periods = 3), 'value': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]})
    id  threshold_date  value
0   1   2018-12-30      0.1
1   1   2018-12-31      0.2
2   2   2019-01-01      0.3
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `merge` for joining on `id` with `query` for filtering:

```
(thresholds.merge(df,on='id',how='left',suffixes=('_x',''))
  .query("threshold_date_x > threshold_date").reindex(columns=df.columns))
```

---

```
   id threshold_date  value
0   1     2018-12-30    0.1
1   1     2018-12-31    0.2
2   2     2019-01-01    0.3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a condition like the following for this:

```
mask = df['threshold_date'] < pd.to_datetime('2019-01-01') # the threshold date 
df = df[mask]
```

Comment: I am looking to select rows for a different threshold date per id, not the same date for the whole DataFrame